# Polynomial transformations and Vieta's formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $f(x)$ be a monic, cubic polynomial with $f(0)=-2$ and $f(1)=−5$. If the sum of all solutions to $f(x+1)=0$ and to $f\big(\frac1x\big)=0$ are the same, what is $f(2)$?

From $f(0)$ I got that $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx-2$ and from $f(1)=-5$ that $a+b = -4$ however I'm not sure how to use the info about the transformations to find $f(2).$ It seems that $(x+1)$ is a root for $f(x+1)$ and the same logic applies for $f\big(\frac1x\big)$?

Should I use Vieta's here or what's the appropriate way to go?

Comment: You have a typo there: it shoud be "...and from $\;f(\color{red}1)=-5\ldots\;$"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Edited.

Comment: Hi Nate, I think you should accept an answer from below and close the question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Done it!

Comment: Thanks, Nate. Really liked your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $\alpha - 1$ is a root of $f(x+1)$ (and vice-versa). So the sum of roots of $f(x+1)$ is the sum of roots of $f(x)$, minus $3$ which by Vieta' formula is $-a$ minus $3 =-a-3$.

Now, the roots of $f(\frac 1x) = \frac{-2x^3+bx^2+ax+1}{x^3}$  are also the roots of $-2x^3+bx^2+ax+1$, the *reciprocal polynomial* of $f$. The sum of roots of this polynomial is $\frac b2$ by Vieta's formula.

Finally, $-a-3= \frac b2$. Conclude.

Comment: How come the sum of the roots for $f(x+1)$ are the sum of the roots for $f(x)$ minus $3$? This is what I don't really see?

Comment: See, if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ , then $\alpha-1$ is a root of $f(x+1)$, because $f((\alpha-1)+1) = f(\alpha) = 0$. Conversely, if $\beta$ is a root of $f(x+1)$ then $\beta+1$ is a root of $f(x)$. Now, suppose the roots of $f(x)$ are $d,e,f$ (There are exactly three roots, counting multiplicity). Then, the roots of $f(x+1)$ are $d-1,e-1,f-1$, from our reasoning above. Finally, the sum of roots of $f(x)$ is $d+e+f$. That of $f(x+1)$ is $d-1+e-1+f-1 = d+e+f - 3$, which is the sum of roots of $f(x)$ minus $3$.

Answer (score 0):

When $f(x+1)=0$, we have,
$$(x+1)^3+a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)-2=0$$
Whose sum of roots can be obtained by "negative of coefficient of $x^2$ upon coefficient of $x^3$", which comes out to be $-\frac{3+a}{1}$.
Similarly, when $f(\frac 1x)=0$, we have,
$$\frac {1}{x^3}+a\frac{1}{x^2}+b\frac{1}{x}-2=0$$
Since $x\neq 0$, we can rearrange and get
$$-2x^3+bx^2+ax+1=0$$
Whose sum of roots is simply $\frac b2$. So,
$$\frac b2 = -3-a$$
Use that with the condition for $f(1)=5$ and solve for $a,b$. Then substitute $x=2$. Ta-da!

Comment: Isn't the coefficient of $x^2$ just $a$ and for $x^3$ it's 1?

Comment: You're forgetting the $x^2$ from the expansion of $(x+1)^3$